# Why isn't method String.indexOf part of interface CharSequence?

Tags: java, string, indexof, charsequence

I can't see any drawbacks in making [`String.indexOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28int%29) part of the interface [`CharSequence`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html). The benefit would be that other classes like StringBuffer or StringBuilder would need to implement the indexOf methods too.

So is there any design reason why `indexOf` should only be part of `String`?

Thank you.

Comment: So what you're asking is: Why doesn't `CharSequence` have an `indexOf` method?

Comment: StringBuffer and StringBuilder do have indexOf methods, though...

Comment: @Thilo - Which sort of begs the question of why doesn't CharSequence specify that behavior? (And although java.nio.CharBuffer and javax.swing.text.Segment don't implement `indexOf`, they easily could.)

Comment: Why doesn't StringBuilder have `contains`? I guess only the API designers can answer these kind of questions (not voting to close, though, because that may have been discussed on some mailing list, and someone might know).

Comment: @Shakedown Yes, that's my question, because `indexOf` suits to every class that currently implements `CharSequence`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am not sure what is the reason for this but I can give an example of class that implements `CharSequence`. It is `java.nio.CharBuffer`.

Theoretically it could implement `indexOf()` by calling `charAt()` in loop. But it will not work as user expects. We cannot distinguish between 2 situations: character is not there yet and character is not there and will not be there. In second case `indexOf()` should return -1 by contract. In first case it should wait until all bytes arrive. But CharBuffer belongs to *non-blocking IO*, so it cannot block.

I believe this explains at least one of the possible reasons.

EDIT:

Following very valuable comment by @Pacerier I want to add the following.
IMHO `CharSequence` as a very generic interface that is used in different circumstances. The most well known implementors of this interface are `String`, `StringBuffer` and `StringBuilder` that hold the whole content in data structure that allows direct access to any character. This is wrong however in general case. `java.nio.CharBuffer` is an example of such case.

Comment: That's putting the cart before the horse. You merely argued that CharBuffer shouldn't be a CharSequence, and not that indexof shouldn't be in CharSequence.

Comment: @Pacerier, thank you for your comment. Please take a look on addition to my answer that hopefully moves the horse forward. :)

Comment: It seems that there ought to be(but there isn't sadly) a separate interface that provides indexOf() methods that both String and StringBuilder implement, so that you can pass either into a method and easily call indexOf() off of it.

Answer (score 3):

I think that's merely an oversight, as `indexOf` operation makes sense for any sort of sequence.

Answer (score 2):

Java 8 may solve some of these problems. It will allow default implementations on interfaces. e.g.

```
interface List {
    void sort() default Collections.sort(this);
}
```

This allow additional methods to be added to interfaces without placing a burden on all implementers to implement that method.

Comment: How would this work for for example `java.nio.CharBuffer` in the case that AlexR mentions in his answer? A default implementation of `indexOf()` wouldn't solve the problem he mentions.

Comment: If you use a method on a CharBuffer or StringBuilder or any mutable object, you don't have a return code for its `false now but might be true if you change something`. It could equally be `true now but false if you change something` such as the data, position or limit is changed.  You can only return true/false based on what is there now.